# Populate ListView on other ListView itemtap event in Sencha Touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I’m a newbie in Sencha touch development so I don’t know, is this right question or wrong, basically I’ve added TabPanel and within the first tab I’ve added a ListView within the NavigationView. So if anybody tapping listview row item then it will populate other listview with selected item as title of second list. How can perform this task?

This is treeview structure of UI part.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at code its not very clear but basically you need to handle `itemtap` event in which you have to get reference of `titlebar/toolbar` and set the data of tapped record to it. Something like this:

```
itemtap: function(list, index, item, rec) {
    Ext.getCmp("orderEntryListTitleBarId").setTitle(rec.get('name'));
}
```